# .htaccess does not work with umlauts and (POST) URIs

Tags: .htaccess

I need your help with my .htaccess file (these files are one of my favorite tasks :-)). My current .htaccess looks so:

```
# Start rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on 

# Check if no file, link or directory is requested
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Do not rewrite install and admin
RewriteRule ^admin$ admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^install$ install/ [R=301,L]

# Pass the requested path to index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ index.php?p=$1/$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]

# Define error document for all errors
ErrorDocument 401 index.php?p=error
ErrorDocument 403 index.php?p=error
ErrorDocument 404 index.php?p=error
ErrorDocument 410 index.php?p=error
```

The main functionality works correct, but I have the following problem:

If I generate an error (for example accessing `/unknownFolder`), the error page is loaded as wished. But if I have umlauts (especially ä, ü, ö, ß) in my URI, there will be only the output `index.php?p=error`. Any explanation or solution for that ridiculous problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't match those characters: `([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)`. Try changing those groupings to `([^/.]+)` so that match everything except slashes and dots:

```
# Pass the requested path to index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?p=$1/$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

What's probably happening is because those umlat characters aren't being matched by those rules, they're not properly routed to the `index.php` file and thus 404.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just works now :-) But I just do not understand, what the rewrite rule has to do with the ErrorDocuments. Would be nice you can explain this further, but this is not necessary. Is there also a solution to make the ErrorDocuments relative to the path of the .htaccess, something like `dirname(__FILE__)` for .htaccess?

Comment: @RichardReiber There are 2 things going on here. A request goes through a pipeline of modules and things process it until finally, it maps to a resource (like a file in the filesystem). The `RewriteRule` that routes the request to `index.php` actually *changes* the URI, so that when that request finally ends up at the end of the pipeline, the URI is `/index.php?p=umlats` or whatever. Since `index.php` exists, it gets mapped and the script runs. However, if that rule **doesn't** match, the umlat URI makes it all the way to the end of the pipeline, and since that's not a resource, it 404's

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Have you just a method for making the ErrorDocument relative to .htaccess?

Comment: @RichardReiber you may need to detect that, the `ErrorDocument` directive expects an absolute URL, so you can't make it relative to a certain directory. So in the php script, you can detect via server variables.

Comment: Can you explain me what is the difference between `([^/.]+)` and `([^.]+)`? With the second variant all works just as I want. :-)

Comment: The ^ in the square brackets means "anything except the following". So `[^/.]` means anything except a slash and period while `[^.]` means anything except period